# Visual Studio and ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : can not scaffolding the view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Working with ASP.NET Core 6 MVC, I right-click in a controller's action and selecting "Add View --> Razor view (not empty)"

[image: Pic]

After clicking "Add", the following error appears :

[image: Error]

Scaffolding was working well until about yesterday. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: have you installed the design and generator of the NuGet package? make sure they are all compatible with each other in terms of version

Comment: Yes I have and they are compatible with each other but it still get error somehow

Comment: Hi @AnhHuyNguyen, pls share your project file and check your `Error List` panel in your visual studio if any error message.

Comment: It was an update error, and it solved. Thank you for you kindness